# Different between (CASE WHEN column= value THEN result ) AND (CASE column WHEN value THEN result )

Tags: sql

I usually write case statement as (CASE WHEN column= value  THEN result) But then I found some person wrote as (CASE column WHEN value THEN result) and the result is different as the code below

```
select  A.value,

CASE  A.value
  WHEN NULL
  THEN CAST('N' AS VARCHAR(1))
  ELSE CAST( A.value AS VARCHAR(1))
END AS CASE_TYPE_1,

CASE WHEN  A.value IS NULL
  THEN CAST('N' AS VARCHAR(1))
  ELSE CAST( A.value AS VARCHAR(1))
END AS CASE_TYPE_2

from A AS A
```

## result

```
A.value      CASE_TYPE_1     CASE_TYPE_2 
NULL             NULL             N
```

I was wondering how the logic of CASE_TYPE_1 and CASE_TYPE_2 differ?

Ps. I wrote and test the script on Azure Databricks

Comment: I'd instead do `CAST( COALESCE(A.value, 'N') AS VARCHAR(1))`.

Comment: The difference you get is because `A.value = NULL` evaluates to unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value can never equal `NULL`. Your first option will be executed as A.value = null which can never be true.
This option can only be used when checking for a specific value, not for checking if `IS NULL` or not. For example, these two `CASE WHEN` constructs will produce the identic result:

```
SELECT A.value,
CASE A.value
  WHEN 1
  THEN CAST('N' AS VARCHAR(1))
  ELSE CAST(A.value AS VARCHAR(1))
END AS CASE_TYPE_1,
CASE WHEN A.value = 1
  THEN CAST('N' AS VARCHAR(1))
  ELSE CAST(A.value AS VARCHAR(1))
END AS CASE_TYPE_2
FROM A;
```

Using `CASE WHEN` in order to just replace `NULL` values is mostly not necessary.

`COALESCE` will do the same:

```
SELECT A.value,
CAST(COALESCE(A.value, 'N') AS VARCHAR(1)) AS yourResult
FROM A;
```

You can verify those things here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AEyY9eat)